# constraint formulation in inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've the following problem. Take a look at this part of query

```
inner join tObjClassifier azoc WITH (NOLOCK index=XAK1tDepClassifier)
             on azoc.ObjType = 8
        and azoc.ParentID = @ObjClassifierID
                    and azoc.Brief = azfo.Brief
                    and case 
                          when PATINDEX( ('%' + ltrim(rtrim(azn.Brief)) + '%' ) , azoc.Param) is null then azn.NodeType = 2 
                          else PATINDEX( ('%' + ltrim(rtrim(azn.Brief)) + '%' ) , azoc.Param)>0 
                        end
```

here , I'm interested in this part

```
and case 
                          when PATINDEX( ('%' + ltrim(rtrim(azn.Brief)) + '%' ) , azoc.Param) is null then azn.NodeType = 2 
                          else PATINDEX( ('%' + ltrim(rtrim(azn.Brief)) + '%' ) , azoc.Param)>0 
                        end
```

How can I do this part without getting errors. Briefly, If condition `PATINDEX( ('%' + ltrim(rtrim(azn.Brief)) + '%' ) , azoc.Param)>0`
not satisfied, disregard this condition and use this `azn.NodeType = 2` condition. Thanks.

we can rearrange above condition as this also:

```
and case 
                          when ltrim(rtrim(azn.Brief)) = azoc.Param is null then azn.NodeType = 2 
                          else ltrim(rtrim(azn.Brief)) = azoc.Param) 
                        end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PATINDEX returns the starting position of the first occurrence of a pattern in a specified expression, or zeros if the pattern is not found. So try use `OR` condition:

```
 ...

 and azoc.Brief = azfo.Brief
 and 
   (
     (PATINDEX( ('%' + ltrim(rtrim(azn.Brief)) + '%' ) , azoc.Param)>0)
     OR 
     (azn.NodeType = 2)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for those entries that don't satisfy first condition, when first condition is satisfied, this query also select those row where second condition is also satisfied

Comment: @SherzodMuminov: Yes. But if the first condition is TRUE the second doesn't matter. So it is equivalent to your case statement.